# Trouble with the assignment of values to pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm currently trying to write a function in MatLab which loops over each pixel, takes the mean intensity of the pixels within a radius around it and then applies that intensity to the central pixel, effectively blurring the image.

I start by declaring the function and finding the maximum width and height of the image, `nx` and `ny`:

```
function [] = immean(IMAGE, r)

[nx, ny] = size(IMAGE);
```

I then create a completely black image of the same size as the image variable `IMAGE`. This is so that I can store the value of each pixel, once the mean intensity of its neighbourhood has been found.

```
average = zeros(size(IMAGE));
```

I then loop through the image:

```
for x = 1:nx
  for y = 1:ny
```

and apply a series of if-statements to deal with cases where the radius of the circle around the pixel does not fit the image. (For example, a pixel at (1,1) with a radius of 5 would have a starting point of -4, which would cause an error):

```
 if x-r <= 0
     startx = 1;
 else
     startx = x-r;
 end

 if x+r > nx
     endx = nx;
 else
     endx = x+r;
 end

 if y-r <= 0
     starty = 1;
 else
     starty = y-r;
 end

 if y+r > ny
     endy = ny;
 else
     endy = y+r;
 end
```

This effectively creates a square of values that may fall under the domain of the circular sample, which speeds up the program dramatically. After that, I iterate through the values within this square and find any pixels which fall within the radius of the central pixel. The intensities of these pixels are then added to a variable called `total` and the count `pixelcount` increments:

```
 total = 0;
 pixelcount = 0;

 for xp = startx : endx

   for yp = starty : endy  

         if (x-xp)^2 + (y-yp)^2 <= r^2
           total = total + uint64(IMAGE(xp, yp));
           pixelcount = pixelcount + 1;
         end
   end
 end
```

I then find the mean intensity of the circular sample of pixels, by dividing `total` by `pixelcount` and then plug that value into the appropriate pixel of the completely black image `average`:

```
 mean = total / pixelcount;
 average(x,y) = mean;
```

The trouble is: this isn't working. Instead of a blurred version of the original image, I get an entirely white image instead. I'm not sure why - when I take the `;` from the last line, it shows me that `mean` constitutes many values - it's not like they're all 255. So I figure that there must be something wrong with the assignment line `average(x,y) = mean;`, but I can't find out what that is.

Can anyone see why this is going wrong?

Comment: What class is average? Probably it's a double and here 0 is black and 1 is white. Convert back to uint8 at the end or convert to the 0 1 range at the beginning using `im2double`

Comment: why aren't using `imfilter` with box filter?

Comment: @Daniel I tried changing `average = zeros(size(IMAGE));` to `average = im2double(zeros(size(IMAGE)));` at the beginning of the code. Then I tried adding `uint8(average);` to the end, after `average(x,y) = mean;` but neither worked. Is this what you were advising or have I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: @Shai I've been told that I can't use certain MatLab tricks, like `pdist()` or `meshgrid` - maybe `imfilter` falls into the same category? I know that I have to manually create the `r` by `r` square from which the circular sample is taken.

Comment: @Daniel Also, rather weirdly, when I just enter `average`, I can see that the image is made of many different intensities, rather than everything being white. So maybe there's something wrong with `imshow` here?

Comment: @Daniel Just changed `uint64(IMAGE(xp, yp))` to `im2double(IMAGE(xp, yp))`. Seems to have worked. Thanks!